# When adding a new address, second field is not clear

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield, textformfield

So, I have an address feature and when I have an address saved the second adress doesnt clear the field.

1- Have an adress saved.
2- Click on add another address
3- See second field

Expected- should be empty
Actual- contains info from prev adress

I have tried to clear the controller inside the save function but it didnt work.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocConsumer<AddressCubit, AddressState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    _handleStateChanged(state);
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(S.of(context).address_title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  GoogleMap(
                    key: _mapsKey,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(state.latitude, state.longitude),
                      zoom: defaultCameraZoom,
                    ),
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      _controller.complete(controller);
                    },
                    onCameraIdle: () {
                      Future.delayed(
                          const Duration(
                            milliseconds: 500,
                          ), () {
                        _onLocationChanged();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: _topPinDistance,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      Img.locationPin,
                      height: Dimens.locationPinHeight,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: Dimens.defaultPadding,
                  top: 12,
                  right: Dimens.defaultPadding),
              child: Text(
                S.of(context).address_location_info,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.copyWith(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 12, right: 12),
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 8,
                runSpacing: 8,
                children: AddressType.values
                    .map(
                      (e) => InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          context.read<AddressCubit>().onTypeChanged(e);
                        },
                        child: AddressTypeTile(
                            type: e, selected: e == state.selectedType),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(Dimens.defaultPadding, 0,
                  Dimens.defaultPadding, Dimens.defaultPadding),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _addressController,
                    enabled: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: S.of(context).address_street_label,
                        errorText: _addressError,
                        errorMaxLines: 2),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _propertyController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: S.of(context).address_property_label,
                        errorText: _propertyDetailsError,
                        errorMaxLines: 2),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _onSave();
                      setState(() {
                        _propertyController.clear();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(S.of(context).generic_save),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

```
  _onSave() {
if (_validate()) {
  context.read<AddressCubit>().onSave(
        street: _addressController.text,
        propertyDetails: _propertyController.text,
      );
} else {
  setState(() {});
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share your code snippet?

Comment: it seems that after i added setState inside onPress the textfield clears, but It doesnt save the state

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

Source code:

```
    // Fetch the string value of controller using controller.value.text & assign to variable.
    final String address = _addressController.value.text;
    final String property = _propertyController.value.text;

    // Assign those variable's values like this.
    context.read<AddressCubit>().onSave(
          street: address,
          propertyDetails: property,
    );
```

Comment: nope, its not working. It gave me same result

Comment: See my code snippet here: https://i.postimg.cc/X7kch3Ht/Screenshot-2023-08-24-at-5-20-24-PM.png